# How to calculate a formula that takes different columns of a dataframe with the same suffix in the name and create a new column?

Tags: r, dataframe

I have a dataframe in R that contains the following columns structure (in a bigger scale):

```
  Material_code  actual_202009  actual_202010  actual_202011  pred_202009  pred_202010  pred_202011  
      111              30              44              24            25           52           27
      112              19              70              93            23           68           100
```

I would like to add new columns to the dataframe containing the respective error measure:

```
|actual - pred|/ actual * 100%
```

Obtaining this:

```
Material_code  actual_202009  actual_202010  actual_202011  pred_202009  pred_202010  pred_202011 MAPE_202009 MAPE_202010 MAPE_202011
      111              30              44              24            25           52          27     16.67%      18.18%       12.5%
      112              19              70              93            23           68          100    21.05%       2.86%        7.52%
```

I tried to create the new columns using `ends_with()` to select the previuous, but I am not getting it right. Can you please help?

*** EDIT to include easier way to generate the dataframe

```
df <- data.frame(Material_code = c(111,112),
                    actual_202009 = c(30,19),
                    actual_202010 = c(44,70),
                    actual_202011 = c(24,93), 
                    pred_202009 = c(25,23),
                    pred_202010 = c(52,68),
                    pred_202011 = c(27,100))
```

Comment: please share `dput(toyData)` so it's easier to copy and work with it.

Comment: @PavoDive is this what you mean, for example?

```dummy <- data.frame(Material_code = c(111,112,113),actual_202009 = c(30,19,45), actual_202010 = c(44,70,67), actual_202011 = c(24,93,46), pred_202009 = c(25,23,50),  pred_202010 = c(52,68,NA),  pred_202011 = c(27,100,40))```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Get the column names of all `'actual'` and `'pred'` columns and you can perform all the mathematical calculations on them directly.

```
actual_cols <- sort(grep('actual', names(df), value = TRUE))
pred_cols <- sort(grep('pred', names(df), value = TRUE))
new_cols <- sub('pred', 'MAPE', pred_cols)

df[new_cols] <- abs(df[actual_cols] - df[pred_cols])/df[actual_cols] * 100
df

#  Material_code actual_202009 actual_202010 actual_202011 pred_202009
#1           111            30            44            24          25
#2           112            19            70            93          23

#  pred_202010 pred_202011 MAPE_202009 MAPE_202010 MAPE_202011
#1          52          27        16.7       18.18       12.50
#2          68         100        21.1        2.86        7.53
```

**data**

```
df <- structure(list(Material_code = 111:112, actual_202009 = c(30L, 
19L), actual_202010 = c(44L, 70L), actual_202011 = c(24L, 93L
), pred_202009 = c(25L, 23L), pred_202010 = c(52L, 68L), pred_202011 = c(27L, 
100L)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

Answer (score 1):

A bit more verbose from the tidyverse:

```
library(tidyverse)
df %>%
  pivot_longer(cols = -Material_code) %>%
  separate(name, into = c("type", "time"), sep = "_") %>%
  pivot_wider(names_from = type) %>%
  mutate(MAPE = abs(actual - pred)/actual*100) %>%
  pivot_wider(values_from = c(actual, pred, MAPE),
              names_from = time)
```

gives:

```
# A tibble: 2 x 10
  Material_code actual_202009 actual_202010 actual_202011 pred_202009 pred_202010 pred_202011 MAPE_202009 MAPE_202010 MAPE_202011
          <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>       <int>       <int>       <int>       <dbl>       <dbl>       <dbl>
1           111            30            44            24          25          52          27        16.7       18.2        12.5 
2           112            19            70            93          23          68         100        21.1        2.86        7.53
```

Comment: Thank you for the help. It seems like a sophisticated solution. However, I obtain a different output when using your code.

´´´A tibble: 6 x 11
  Material_code   sAPE actual_202009 actual_202010 actual_202011 pred_202009 pred_202010 pred_202011 MAPE_202009
1           111 0.0909            30            NA            NA          25          NA          NA        16.7
2           111 0.0833            NA            44            NA          NA          52          NA        NA ´´´

Comment: If you get a different result, then something does not align in your code, e.g. the data you posted above is not the one you were using for testing my code. I just double-checked with your df data and I get exactly the results you want (which is also identical to what @Ronak Shah posted).

Comment: you are right, I don't know what I changed, but it works now. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

You will help yourself a lot if you try to keep your data in long format: each column has the same kind of data. **Your table is in wide format**, very useful for excel and human visualization, but very cumbersome to deal with in code.

So the first thing you need to do (that's what @deschen did in their answer) is converting your data to long, and then operate on it. A long version of your data will be of the form

```
Material_code    Type    Date   Value
          111  actual  202011      30
```

I will provide a data.table solution, that is basically the same as @deschen's. You may like this one for its speed on large data.

```
library(data.table)

setDT(df1)

df1[, melt(.SD, 1)][, 
               c("type", "date") := tstrsplit(variable, "_", fixed = TRUE)][,
                     dcast(.SD, Material_code + date ~ type)][, 
                         mape := 100 * abs(actual - pred) / actual][]
```

- `melt(.SD, 1)` converts your table from wide to long, keeping only the first column as reference for each record.
- `c("type", "date") := tstrsplit(variable, "_", fixed = TRUE)` creates columns type and date with the corresponding values taken from `variable` (after `melt`ing, `variable` has the former column names).
- `dcast(.SD, Material_code + date ~ type)` converts the long table into wide again. This time, `Material_code` and `date` will be kept in columns, and `type` will be casted into new columns `actual` and `pred`.
- The `:=` is an assignment operator. It creates variable `mape` and assigns the resulting value.
- The last bit, `[]` isn't actually needed. Is there so the result is printed to screen. If you don't need to print the new table to screen, omit it.

Comment: Thank you very much! Your code runs very fast. For me it is was extremely helpful the explanation you provided. I really appreciate it.