# variable values in data.table::melt with patterns

Tags: r, data.table

While answering [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65935389/how-to-calculate-a-formula-that-takes-different-columns-of-a-dataframe-with-the/65937046#65937046) I tried to use the `patterns` functionality together with `data.table::melt`:

```
df1 <- structure(list(Material_code = 111:112, 
                      actual_202009 = c(30L, 19L), 
                      actual_202010 = c(44L, 70L), 
                      actual_202011 = c(24L, 93L), 
                      pred_202009 = c(25L, 23L), 
                      pred_202010 = c(52L, 68L), 
                      pred_202011 = c(27L, 100L)), 
                 class = c("data.table", "data.frame"), 
                 row.names = c(NA, -2L))
```

I wanted to convert that wide table to a long one, separating the `actual` and `pred` values. **I thought** the date part was going to be conserved in the variable, **but it was changed to factor numbers** (1, 2, etc):

```
melt(df1, 1, measure = patterns(actual = "actual_", pred = "pred_"))[1, ]
>    Material_code variable actual pred
> 1:           111        1     30   25
```

I wanted "202009" instead of "1" in the `variable` field.

**I am fully aware I can achieve it the long way, using `tstrsplit`**:

```
melt(df1, 1)[, 
           c("type", "variable") := tstrsplit(variable, "_", fixed = TRUE)][,
                 dcast(.SD, Material_code + date ~ type)]
```

but I was expecting that with `patterns` I could produce a less verbose way.

#### What I've tried:

- I changed `variable.factor = FALSE` (default is true), but it produces the same values in the `variable` column (1, 2, ...), only this time they are strings.

#### Expected output:

I expect the following code to produce the shown output (of course replacing `argument1` and `argument2` with whatever is appropriate):

```
melt(df1, 1, measure = patterns(actual = "actual_", pred = "pred_"), argument1, argument2)[1, ]
>    Material_code variable actual pred
> 1:           111   202009     30   25
```

Is it possible, or definitely one has to go the long way?

Comment: https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/4056#issuecomment-700410374 and https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2551

Comment: Looks like there's a branch [`melt-custom-variable`](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/tree/melt-custom-variable/man) (mentioned here https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/issues/2551#issuecomment-704674133) that might resolve this, unsure of its status or timeline.

Comment: Related: [Convert numeric representation of 'variable' column to original string following melt using patterns](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41883573/convert-numeric-representation-of-variable-column-to-original-string-following)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

With `data.table` 1.14.1 (dev version as of 2021-05-18) it is possible to solve it using the newly incorporated `measure` function. Like this:

```
melt(df1, measure.vars= measure(value.name, date, pattern="(actual|pred)_(.*)"))

   Material_code   date actual pred
1:           111 202009     30   25
2:           112 202009     19   23
3:           111 202010     44   52
4:           112 202010     70   68
5:           111 202011     24   27
6:           112 202011     93  100
```

Check `?measure` as well as the release news for more information.

Comment: I like this answer and the solution. I am not a fan of the fact that almost two years later, it is still in dev (currently tagged as 1.14.9, several hotfix releases in the interim). I'm grateful to the `data.table` team for their efforts, I wonder when they will be comfortable with the new features (`measure()`, `env=`, `DT()`, and countless fixes) to release to CRAN.